# Error Unterminated string constant

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

i have a two wanrning in this line of "Error Unterminated string constant"
i don't now what's the best paractice to use this js cript into my code .
this is the code :

```
 <input   type="submit"  value="Delete"
                onclick="return confirm('vous etes sures d \' avoir supprimer le membre avec le nom = @item.UserName  ');"/>
```

this all of code of this statement :

```
@foreach (var item in Model) { 
      using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "AccountHopital", new { id = item.UserId }))
            {

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserSurname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserEmail)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserBirthday)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserAdress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserPhone)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserCreateAcount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserLastUpdate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoleId)
        </td>
        <td>

        @if (item.UserPicture !=null )
         {
              <img src="@Url.Action("getImgage", "AccountHopital", new { id = item.UserId })" style="height:100px;width:100px"    />
         }
  else
  {
      <img src="~/Images/8.jpeg" style="height:100px;width:100px"  />
  }
         </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserId }) |


                <input   type="submit"  value="Delete"
                    onclick="return confirm('vous etes sures d \' avoir supprimer le membre avec le nom = @item.UserName  ');"/> 


            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {  id=item.UserId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {  id=item.UserId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Manage Account","ManageProfile",new {id = item.UserId})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
}
```

Comment: You need to show us more context. The code above is fine on its own in the HTML, so I'm guessing that this whole thing is *inside* some other code, perhaps some .Net code, perhaps in a string. (If so, you need to escape the backslash, but again, more context is required.)

Comment: ok , i will insert all of code now